# Programmatically add highlighting to shape (path)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make highlighting on mouse over to code-generated paths (Path class i mean). The problem is i'm not using some XAML Templates to bind that code just generate it in C#. I've got already my shapes (Path) but i cant add Style to work with it.

Here's my code:

```
            Setter setter = new Setter();
            setter.Property = Path.FillProperty;
            setter.Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightYellow);

            EventTrigger eTrigger = new EventTrigger();
            eTrigger.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseEnterEvent;


            Style styleMouseIn = new Style();
            styleMouseIn.Setters.Add(setter);
            styleMouseIn.TargetType = typeof(Path);
            styleMouseIn.Triggers.Add(eTrigger);
            BeginStoryboard mouseInAnim = new BeginStoryboard();
            mouseInAnim.Storyboard = new Storyboard();
            eTrigger.Actions.Add(mouseInAnim);
            //path.Style.Setters.Add(setter);
            //path.Style.Triggers.Add(eTrigger);
            path.Style = styleMouseIn;
```

but it's not working.

edit:

```
            Setter setter = new Setter();
            setter.Property = Path.FillProperty;
            setter.Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightYellow);

            ColorAnimation anim1 = new ColorAnimation();
            anim1.To = Colors.Yellow;
            anim1.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            anim1.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

            BeginStoryboard StoryBoad = new BeginStoryboard();
            StoryBoad.Storyboard = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));

            EventTrigger eTrigger = new EventTrigger();
            eTrigger.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseEnterEvent;
            eTrigger.Actions.Add(StoryBoad);

            Style styleMouseIn = new Style();
            styleMouseIn.Setters.Add(setter);
            styleMouseIn.TargetType = typeof(Path);
            styleMouseIn.Triggers.Add(eTrigger);

            StoryBoad.Storyboard.Children.Add(anim1);

            path.Style = styleMouseIn;
```

New version :F

Comment: `The problem is i'm not using some XAML` - That's right. The problem is you're `not` using XAML. If you already know that, why don't you just fix it? delete all this and create a proper XAML-based View and a proper ViewModel and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: Yea, i know this but it's almost done and i feel i'm really close to make it work. Making template would cost me a lot of work and i hope i can avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this. 
This line was the solution:

```
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
```